# Customizing ViewPagerIndicator style

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

In my app, I am trying to style **ViewPagerIndicator**. The pager consists of several fragments. I want something exactly like the picture attached - **the CirclePageIndicator at the bottom right & a title at the bottom left**. However, the CirclePageIndicator is positioned centered by default & if I customize indicator's "**centered**" value false, then it goes to the left. I haven't found any option to move that to the right side as shown in the picture.

[image: Fragments in ViewPager with ViewPagerIndicator]

Another concern is the title of the pager. I have tried with [**PagerTitleStrip**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTitleStrip.html) but this is not actually what I am looking for, this PagerTitleStrip shows the previous & next page's title at the left & right side of the title, but **I want only this page's title - exactly in the same format like the picture.**

BTW, I am using **Jake Wharton's** [**library**](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) for the ViewpagerIndicator.

I am stuck in this issue for several days. I hope someone comes out with his wise thinking & helps me out of this?

Regards. & Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In src / com / viewpagerindicator / CirclePageIndicator.java

add this

//at line 236

```
    if (mRight) {
        longOffset = longSize  - ((count * threeRadius) / 2.0f);
    }
```

//at about line 116

```
public void setRight(boolean right) {
    mRight = right;
    invalidate();
}
```

//line 58

```
private boolean mRight;
```

you could also add some padding if you wanted

Comment: Cool, the VPI problem is solved. Still I have the title issue. I hope you can help int hat case also